# MFC MDI Collecting control states for the "apply" button routine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, apply

It was mentioned in some of my other threads on my app on that my code was incorrect because the apply button is present. I understand that now. It was said to collect the controls and then when apply is hit to send the data.

I have now idea how to approach that. So for the sake of general education. I have 1 `property sheet` and 5 `property pages`. For the sake of just general controls in use. Between all the 5, there are only `radio` controls and `buttons`, no `edit controls` (yet).

Let's assume there are `2 radios buttons` and `1 button` on each page.. where `page 1` is `radio1`, `radio2`, `button 1` and `page 2` is `radio3`, `radio4`, `button2`....and so on.

I know that when the user selects something like a button or radio that the `IsModified(TRUE)` needs to be called to enable the apply button from grayed to active.

What would the code look like to scan all the controls and then apply them? I've never done it and I can't seem to find an example that isn't already super busy to gain the understanding of how to do it.

Anyone have a tutorial or code snippet or build a primer from the controls that I described above that could demonstrate how to execute this?

## Update:

Ok so I have the DDX variables added:

```
void CSettingsUserTabs::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CMFCPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_USER, m_style_3d);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_FLAT_USER, m_style_flat);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_FLAT_SHARED_HORZ_SCROLL_USER, m_style_flat_shared_h_scroll);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_SCROLLED_USER, m_style_3d_scroll);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_ONENOTE_USER, m_style_onenote);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_VS2005_USER, m_style_vs2005);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_USER, m_style_3d_rounded);
    DDX_Control(pDX, STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_SCROLL_USER, m_style_3d_rounded_scroll);
}
```

My radio selection look like:

```
void CSettingsUserTabs::OnBnClicked3dUser()
{
    //AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, STYLE_3D_USER);
    UpdateData(TRUE);
}


void CSettingsUserTabs::OnBnClickedFlatUser()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    //AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, STYLE_FLAT_USER);
    UpdateData(TRUE);
}

..... and the rest of them....
```

So to me, when I click any `radio button`, I expect that it scans all of controls on that property page? If so, all the variables have the values..do I call `IsModified();` to enable the `apply` button...which then executes all the radio values i.e. only one selected? Is that the flow?

## Update 2:

So this is what my modal dialog code is in `MainFrame.cpp`:

```
void CMainFrame::OnSettingsTools()
{
    SettingsSheet SettingsSheet(L"Application Settings");

    CSettingsPowerUser      pgePowerUser;   
    CSettingsToolbars       pgeToolbars;
    CSettingsTheme          pgeTheme;
    CSettingsUserTabs       pgeUserTabs;
    CSettingsReset          pgeReset;    
    
    SettingsSheet.AddPage(&pgeToolbars);
    SettingsSheet.AddPage(&pgeTheme);
    SettingsSheet.AddPage(&pgeUserTabs);
    SettingsSheet.AddPage(&pgePowerUser);
    SettingsSheet.AddPage(&pgeReset);

    INT_PTR nRet = -1;
    nRet = SettingsSheet.DoModal();

    // Handle the return value from DoModal
    switch (nRet)
    {
    case -1:
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Dialog box could not be created!"));
        break;
    case IDABORT:
        // Do something
        AfxMessageBox(_T("ABORT!"));
        break;
    case IDOK:
        // Do something
        OnUserTabStyles(1);
        AfxMessageBox(_T("OK!"));
        break;
    case IDCANCEL:
        // Do something
        AfxMessageBox(_T("CANCEL"));
        break;
    default:
        // Do something
        break;
    };    
}
```

The routine to verify if any of the radios buttons are changed in `SettingsTabs.cpp`:

```
void CSettingsUserTabs::OnTabRadioClicked(UINT nCmdID)
{
    BOOL IsChecked = nCmdID;
    CheckRadioButton(STYLE_3D_USER, STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_SCROLL_USER, nCmdID);
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    m_tabCmdID = nCmdID;
    SetModified();
}
```

What the member variables look like in SettingsUserTabs.cpp:

```
void CSettingsUserTabs::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
    CMFCPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_USER, m_style_3d);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_FLAT_USER, m_style_flat);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_FLAT_SHARED_HORZ_SCROLL_USER, m_style_flat_h_scroll);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_SCROLLED_USER, m_style_3d_scroll);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_ONENOTE_USER, m_style_3d_onenote);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_VS2005_USER, m_style_vs2005);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_USER, m_style_3d_rounded);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_SCROLL_USER, m_style_3d_rounded_scroll);
    }
```

What the constructor looks like in SettingsUserTabs.cpp:

```
CSettingsUserTabs::CSettingsUserTabs()
    : CMFCPropertyPage(IDD_SETTINGS_TABS)
    , m_style_3d(FALSE)
    , m_style_flat(FALSE)
    , m_style_flat_h_scroll(FALSE)
    , m_style_3d_scroll(FALSE)
    , m_style_3d_onenote(FALSE)
    , m_style_vs2005(FALSE)
    , m_style_3d_rounded(FALSE)
    , m_style_3d_rounded_scroll(FALSE)
    , m_tabCmdID(FALSE)
{
}
```

[image: Tabs]

This issue I'm seeing now is when I try to use the member variable `m_tabCmdID` it is coming back to `unknown identifier` so I'm not sure why the member variable isn't be seen. I am was expecting to use it like `OnUserTabStyles(m_tabCmdID);` so that it would pass the argument of the selected button to the method `OnUserTabStyles`. For now I just dumped a `1` in there to see if the mechanism works. I just am not clear how to access the member variable from the SettingsUserTabs.cpp from the `IDOK`. What am I missing?

EDIT: The range of options are sequential in the `resource.h` as 200-207, that is something I'm aware of and I know many don't like range options as they can get corrupted...this is my code, so I have no worries about the range being messed with.

## Update 3:

Ok, so I finally understand the mechanism that Constantine described with the help of:

https://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/10/radio-buttons-in-mfc-visual-studio-2008-c/

I didn't have the tab order right nor did I have the first control set to true for the group.

With that, I now get the values 0-7 mentioned in the button group when I debug as I click each radio button based on its position in the group from 0-7 i.e. 8 buttons. Here is what the code looks like now.

`SettingsUserTabs.cpp`:

```
CSettingsUserTabs::CSettingsUserTabs()
    : CMFCPropertyPage(IDD_SETTINGS_TABS)
    , m_style_tabs(FALSE)
{
}

void CSettingsUserTabs::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CMFCPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, STYLE_3D_USER, m_style_tabs);
}

void CSettingsUserTabs::OnTabRadioClicked(UINT nCmdID)
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    BOOL RadioValueSelected = m_style_tabs; // only here to see 0-7 value for debugging only, not needed, test only
    SetModified();
}
```

The `mainframe.cpp` above (Update 2): `void CMainFrame::OnSettingsTools()` is still the same.

So now here is where my question still isn't clear, I call the `domodal` from `mainframe.cpp`, the member variable `m_style_tabs` is in `SettingsUserTabs.cpp`. When I try to access the member variable, it says unknown identifier when I try to do something like this `after` the domodal `int temp = m_styles_tabs;`. I have a this in the `mainframe.cpp`

```
void CMainFrame::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    CMDIFrameWndEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
```

I would expect that the member would be seen in `mainframe.cpp` so I can process it after the domodal which is what I thought the whole point of this is?

How do I access the member variable so I can do the `OnApply` to it? I think I almost got it, I am just unclear on how to execute the last few steps for the actual apply itself.

## Update 4:

The reason I ask about the restart is when the user selects the `tabs` property page and choose 1 of 8 choices, that option is stored in the registry and read during the `Oncreate` and then uses that style. Since it is `OnCreate` I haven't found a way to "redraw" or use the new `tab` setting except to restart the app. So by doing the reg save > respawn > end old ...I would want the dialog to reopen at the same tab property page so the user can see what the changes are if the `apply` was selected...vs. some dialog that says "restart"..or whatever. Below is the code used to demonstrate how it is working now.

`OutputWnd.cpp`

```
int COutputWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

    // Create User Define tab style:
    int UserTabStyle = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), 0); //Get value from registry
    // If the key doesn't exist, UserTableStyle will be 0 or FALSE;

    if (UserTabStyle != FALSE && UserTabStyle <= 8) { // User selected tab style type

        int EnumUserTabStyle = UserTabStyle - 1; // Fix enum if key doesn't exist.

        if (!m_wndTabs.Create(static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl::Style>(EnumUserTabStyle), rectDummy, this, 1))
        {
            TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
            return -1;      // fail to create
        }
    }
    else { // Default tabs style if Reg key does not exist i.e. new install/program reset
        
        if (!m_wndTabs.Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_FLAT, rectDummy, this, 1))
            {
                TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
                return -1;      // fail to create
            }
    }

… rest of function....
```

## Update 5:

Here is the Apply in use from `SettingsUserTabs.cpp`:

```
BOOL CSettingsUserTabs::OnApply()
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), m_style_tabs); // Save value to registry

    return CMFCPropertyPage::OnApply();
}
```

## Update 6:

Everything to this point is working, I ran into a road block trying to apply lessons learned here and at this link:

[MFC MDI Substituting a class member dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377001/mfc-mdi-substituting-a-class-member-dynamically)

What was done in this topic was for the OutputWnd pane which works brilliantly! My MDI opens a file and uses CTabView and using the link shown in Update 6 allowed me to change the tabs on boot. Now that I have the OutputWnd doing it with `OnApply`, I'm trying to apply it to the document view when a file is loaded. I'm running into an `access violation` when I call the new function I created in `TrainView.cpp` and calling it from `UserSettingsTabs.cpp`. I thought it was the `static_cast` operation, but even if I do a simple `bold` using `GetControlTabs()` that also crashes (Shown in the commented out code, was on boot, now in `OnApply` to test theory). So clearly I need to capture the MDI document but not sure how that is done. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl::Style>(EnumUserTabStyle));
```

But when that crashed with a Cx000000005 access violation, I knew something was wrong on my end. I can't modify the `CTabView` operation, so I'm looking to see if we can fix what I'm doing wrong to have the `OnApply` change the tab styles without restarting as done in the OutputWnd we just fixed.

So as it stands, the `OnApply` that is working and now modded to try an integrate the CTabView functionality:

`SettingsUserTabs.cpp`:

```
BOOL CSettingsUserTabs::OnApply()
{
    BOOL bResult = CMFCPropertyPage::OnApply();
    if (bResult)
    {
        AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), m_style_tabs); // Save value to registry
        ((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndOutput.m_wndTabs.ModifyTabStyle((CMFCTabCtrl::Style)m_style_tabs);     
        ((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndOutput.m_wndTabs.RecalcLayout();

        CTrainView* TrainTabs; // User Call from anywhere method
        TrainTabs->TrainDocUpdateTabsControl();
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

I added the function `CTrainView::TrainDocUpdateTabsControl()` to update the tabs...the rest of the code is fully operation i.e. `void CTrainView::OnInitialUpdate()`

The `TrainView.cpp`:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CTrainView, CTabView)

void CTrainView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: TrainView--CTrainView::OnInitialUpdate()."));

    // add views // cmb         
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CInformationView), AfxStringID(IDS_INFORMATION));
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CChaptersView), AfxStringID(IDS_CHAPTERS));

    // Nicely hack to access protected member
    class CMFCTabCtrlEx : public CMFCTabCtrl
    {
    public:
        void SetDisableScroll() { m_bScroll = FALSE; }
    };

    // One-Liner to Disable navigation control
    ((CMFCTabCtrlEx*)&GetTabControl())->SetDisableScroll();

    GetTabControl().EnableTabSwap(TRUE);
    GetTabControl().SetLocation(CMFCBaseTabCtrl::Location::LOCATION_BOTTOM);    
    //GetTabControl().SetActiveTabBoldFont(TRUE);
    GetTabControl().EnableAutoColor(TRUE);

    // Modify User Define tab style:
    int UserTabStyle = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), 0); //Get value from registry
    
    // If the key doesn't exist, UserTableStyle will be 0 or FALSE;
    if (UserTabStyle != FALSE && UserTabStyle <= 8) { // User selected tab style type

        int EnumUserTabStyle = UserTabStyle - 1; // Fix enum if key doesn't exist.
        GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl::Style>(EnumUserTabStyle));

    }
    else { // Default tabs style if Reg key does not exist i.e. new install/program reset

        GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_FLAT);
    }

    CTabView::OnInitialUpdate();    
}

void CTrainView::TrainDocUpdateTabsControl()
{   
    CTabView::AssertValid();
    GetTabControl().SetActiveTabBoldFont(TRUE); << CAUSES Cx000000005 ACCESS ERROR CRASH WHEN CALLED.

    //int EnumUserTabStyle;
    //int UserTabStyle = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), 0); //Get value from registry
    //((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl::Style>(EnumUserTabStyle)); 
}
```

Update 6 EDIT:

The `tabview` is created from `Application.cpp` like this:

```
//Load Train Template
m_pkDocTrainTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
    IDR_TRAIN, // Loads TRAIN operation
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CTrainDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CTrainView));
AddDocTemplate(m_pkDocTrainTemplate);
```

I tried to cast the `m_pkDocTrainTemplate` as I thought that was the pointer? Since it is MDI, I wasn't sure if there was an index issue since there can be multiple docs open simultaneously?

Comment: I would recommend that you use the `DDX/DDV` feature to read the controls' values. You can add class variables with the Wizard, of proper type for each control (eg strings for edit-boxes, integer for radio-buttons, boolean for check boxes etc) and call `UpdateData(TRUE)` to read the control contents into the variables. No need to use Win32 functions here (although you actually can). The wizard will add the DDX/DDV routine calls. Events like `OnChange()` (`EN_CHANGE`) can be used to enable the Apply button.

Comment: I'll give that a go....thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I've updated the first post, is that how it should look?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, sorry. You should bind dialog controls to "Value" rather than "Control" variables (in the "Category" combo), so this will generate CString, int, BOOL etc variables instead of control-type ones, and functions like `DDX_Check()`, `DDX_Radio()` or `DDV_MaxChars()`. The `DDV_` functions perform validation, like min/max for ints, max length for stings etc. And `UpdateData(TRUE)` is typically called in the `OnOK()` event, and validates and copies the contents of ALL controls. In the `OnClicked()` or `OnChange()` events you should just enable the "Apply" button.

Comment: I went back and redid the whole thing, the ddx is still showing up, but it added the member variables right after the constructor. That seem to make sense? I just need to figure out how to do the rest of it.

Comment: No, this is not OK, you have a group of 8 radio-buttons, 8 boolean variables and 8 `DDX_Radio()` calls. You should instead have one int variable, bound to the 1st button in the group, and one `DDX_Radio()` call. The variable will be getting values 0..7 (-1 means no selection).

Comment: I store the options the user selects into the registry. Then they persist and all the calling code has to do is read the registry.

Comment: I have an Update 3 above, I got the values and method mention by @ConstantineGeorgiou My questions are how to access them member variable, see update 3.

Comment: Where is the `TrainTabs` pointer supposed to point to? It's uninitialized.

Comment: I added an edit to Update 6. I "think" this is what I should be looking at?

Comment: So I added:  `CTrainView* TrainTabs = (CTrainView*)AfxGetApp();` .. It doesn't crash now but also doesn't execute the Bold update, so not entirely sure that was the right pointer?

Comment: This is also wrong. How can you cast an app to a view? They are different objects, and the cast won't somehow find the view you want. You need to find the views (`GetFirstViewPosition()/GetNextView()`) and apply the changes to the active one or to all. An application may contain multiple view windows. An MDI app may even contain none (if all documents are closed). This can't be done this way, and asking an additional question in the forum wouldn't help much either, I'm afraid. (cont)

Comment: You seem to have difficulty understanding basic OOP concepts. I would recommend that you take some OOP (and more specifically C++) courses, before trying to work with the MFC Object Model. You need to learn concepts like classes, instances, objects' creation and lifetime, class variables and references, inheritance, overrides, virtual and pure-virtual members, static vs non-static members, visibility rules etc etc. It's not that we don't want to help, but this way you won't get far.

Comment: You are correct in your assessment, I'm an Senior Electrical EE by trade and live is C mostly for firmware and things like that. I acquired the useful long abandoned code and have come a long way with it. It has been a learning tool for me and I've learned alot...from you and others. While I appreciate the take more classes approach, this is more of a pet project and I will find a way to make it work. Thank you for all you've done. I will figure it out no matter what it takes. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of an application I wrote some time ago. It's a simple "Settings" dialog. Unlike yours, this one is derived from `CDialogEx`. But as `CPropertyDialog` is derived from `CDialog`, these apply in your case too.

Using the Wizard, I added member variables to the dialog class, bound to the dialog controls. Choose "Value", rather than "Control" in the "Category" combo in the Wizard. These are declared in the class definition. For simplicity, I only show three. There is a CString, an int and a BOOL variable, bound to an edit, a combo-box (drop-down list) and a check-box control respectively.

```
class CSettingsDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    .
    .
public:
    CString m_DBConn;
    int m_DumpSQL;
    BOOL m_bLineNums;
}
```

In the implementation, the Wizard has modified the constructor and the `DoDataExchange()` member functions:

```
CSettingsDlg::CSettingsDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CSettingsDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_DBConn(_T(""))
    , m_DumpSQL(0)
    , m_bLineNums(FALSE)
{
}

void CSettingsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_DBCONN, m_DBConn);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_DBConn, 255);
    DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_COMBO_DUMPSQL, m_DumpSQL);
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_DumpSQL, 0, 2);
    DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_CHECK_LINENUMS, m_bLineNums);
}
```

The values in the constructor are the initial (default) ones. The `DoDataExchange()` function calls the `DDX/DDV` routines. The DDX routines perform the transfer of data (controls<->variables), while the DDV ones the validation - they are optional. The `DoDataExchange()` function is called by `UpdateData()`. Also, the default implementation of `OnOK()` calls `UpdateData(TRUE)`, and if successful closes the dialog.

You will need to enable the Apply button if something has been modified. You can capture notification messages like `EN_CHANGE`, `EN_UPDATE`, `BN_CLICKED` etc (add an event in the property editor) and call the `SetModified()` function - this can prove quite tedious, but I can't see any other way to do it.

Such a dialog class can be used in the application as shown below:

```
void CChildView::OnSetoptions()
{
    // Create a Settings-dialog class instance
    CSettingsDlg sd;  // Main application window as parent - will block every UI item in the application

    // Set initial values for the member variables
    sd.m_DBConn = szDBconn;
    sd.m_DumpSQL = nDumpSQL;
    sd.m_bLineNums = bDumpLineNums;

    if (sd.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        // Store the values entered by the user
        lstrcpyn(szDBconn, sd.m_DBConn, MAX_PATH);
        nDumpSQL = sd.m_DumpSQL;
        bDumpLineNums = sd.m_bLineNums;
    }
}
```

---

---

**EDIT :**

I have a usage example in the code section just above. The procedure is create an instance of the dialog class, set the member variables' values (initial values, eg read from the registry), call `DoModal()` and if successful store (copy) the variables somewhere else (if not discard them). This should be done in some event handler, like `CMainFrame::OnSettingsTools()` in Update2. The `CMainFrame::DoDataExchange()` override makes no sense.

It's quite strange that you can't access the `m_style_tabs` variable. Isn't it a non-static, public member of the `CSettingsUserTabs` class? It should be declared in SettingsUserTabs.h. Won't it work if you acceess it as `pgeUserTabs.m_style_tabs`? In the `CSettingsUserTabs` class functions it can accessed simply as `m_style_tabs`. Also I see it is initialized as `FALSE` in the constructor. Is it a `BOOL` and not an `int`? (btw BOOL is defined as int in Win32, so the compiler won't complain) But the Wizard generates an int variable for radio-buttons, optionally with range validation as well.

Another point, you don't normally need to call `UpdateData(TRUE)` in `CSettingsUserTabs::OnTabRadioClicked()`. Please leave only the `SetModified()` call there. `UpdateData(TRUE)` is typically called in the `OnOK()` function. And usually you don't need to override these, because the default implementation is sufficient. The [CPropertyPage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpropertypage-class?view=msvc-160) btw mentions that *The default implementation of `OnApply` calls `OnOK`*.

---

---

**EDIT 2 :**

In `OnApply()` you should first check if validation was successful. Also, `OnCreate()` isn't a "method" that can be called directly. It should be considered an "event". It's called by the framework when a window is created. You should instead call `Create()`. In your case you can destroy the Output Window and create it anew (with the new style). But, I see that the `CMFCTabCtrl` class has a `ModifyTabStyle()` function, which you can try calling, (without destroying the windows and creating it again). So, your code would become:

```
BOOL CSettingsUserTabs::OnApply()
{
    BOOL bResult = CMFCPropertyPage::OnApply();
    if (bResult)
    {
        AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), m_style_tabs); // Save value to registry
        ((CMainFraime*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndOutput.m_wndTabs.ModifyTabStyle((CMFCTabCtrl::Style)m_style_tabs);
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

The above code won't compile, because the `m_wndOutput` and `m_wndTabs` members are protected. You will have to make them public.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, the good thing is that what you mentioned earlier I was able to apply and have something very close to your `.h` 3 items. I have something similar to the `constructor variables` (using mine), and the `ddx data exchange`..all look similar (which I'll post when I get further in). I have a `case` structure to capture my `radio buttons`. The only thing is, I don't have an `IDOK()`, or `IDAPPLY()`, I assume I create it.. The other things, where does `UpdateData()` get called, before `IDOK/IDAPPLY`...as it isn't shown on your snippet.

Comment: For radio buttons, WinAPI indeed does not offer anything special, just getting the check-state of each button. But a radio-button group is a "multiple-choice" type UI item (just like drop-down-list combos), so an int "state" would be preferable. MFC does this for you, with the `DDX_Radio()` routine. It's wizard-generated. You can bind an int member variable to the 1st radio button; it must have the group style set (the others NOT). The tab order must also be correct. Test your dialog resource (Format->Test Dialog, or Ctrl+T) to make sure that it works OK.

Comment: Some clarifications, there is no `IDOK()` function. Dialog-boxes typically have an "OK" button, usually with the "default" (`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`) style set (captures the ENTER key), and a control id of `IDOK`. Clicking this button calls the dialog's `OnOK()` event. The default (`CDialog::OnOK()`) implementation, as I described in the post, calls `UpdateData(TRUE)`, and if successful closes the dialog. That's OK in my case, no need for an override. You can find such stuff in the MFC sources, go Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files, your text, and in "Look In" select Visual C++ Source Directories

Comment: I created an Update 2 in the original post, I think the way I did it satisfies your concern. The actual code is there now so you can see exactly what I'm doing, I'm hoping I have followed your guidance correctly.

Comment: I got it working .. `pgeUserTabs.m_style_tabs` was my fix, I was unclear how to do it, that clarified it. I have the `apply` and `ok` functions working. I converted the `BOOL` to `int`, dumped the ddx exchange from main and adapted the `UpdateData(FALSE)` to update the controls when the dialog opens and tabs is selected. I do have one final question, the tabs change requires an app restart, I have that easy peasy, how to I activate the "tabs" list link after I send the menu command to open the settings dialog from the menu? Want to say thanks for all your help!

Comment: `UpdateData(FALSE)`, which means variables->controls, is not usualy needed to be called explicitly, as the default implementation of the dialog classes does it already. The variables must have been assigned their values first, as I show in my example. I don't understand why you need to restart the app after changing something in the controls. The class instances (`pgeTheme`, `pgeUserTabs` etc) are local in `OnSettingsTools()`, so they would be destroyed on exit, and there should be no difference in the 2nd call. Maybe post some more code?

Comment: I added an `Update 4` to show what I'm doing to clarify why I asked about the restart to tab on the `Property Page`.

Comment: Why not override `OnApply()` instead? In the override call the default implemntation (will call `UpdateData(TRUE)` ) and if successful store the content into the registry and destroy and create again the output window pane. It will be redrawn (using the new settings from the registry), while the settings dialog won't even need to be closed.

Comment: I added an Update 5 on how my `Apply` looks, I've been trying to figure out if `OnCreate` could be called again, couldn't really find the answer. So what would syntax look like from SettingsUserTabs.cpp to OutputWnd.cpp as there are two variables being passed specifically `(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` ? I follow the idea from the beginning, not sure how to implement that. If I can get that working I'll be done with the Q&A I think! Best,

Comment: The code worked, but only when I hit ok? When I click apply, it breaks in the code...but the tabs only updated `after` I hit the `ok` button. But that is great to know it can be done without a restart. FYI, typo found CMainFraime > CMainFrame. Just incase someone follows this path... :)

Comment: I got it.. added: `((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndOutput.m_wndTabs.RecalcLayout();` and now when I use apply, updates when pressed! I think I am good for now...will update if I hit a roadblock..TY!!

Comment: I added an Update 6, nothing wrong, "new" issue as a result of trying to integrate this in the MDI. Full explanation in Update 6. TY.